# How to use Magento 2 product add/edit form category tree structure in custom form?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to use Magento 2 product add/edit form category tree structure in the custom form

I got some sol. from StackOverflow and some other websites

but it is not working properly

I have tried :

```
    $fieldset->addField(
        'category_ids',
        'Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Category',
        [
            'name' => 'category_ids',
            'title' => 'Category',
            'label' => 'Category'
        ]
    );

<head>
    <css src="Magento_Catalog::catalog/category-selector.css"/>
</head>
```

this code and added this CSS in my custom form

but it is showing like this

[image]

but I need as same as product add/edit form

[image]

how can I do that

please share some suggestions.....

Comment: Hello @Yagendra, Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating the form using ui component you can get category input from following xml

```
<field name="parent">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Parent Category</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.parent</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

I am trying to figure how I can create a button and modal to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a multiselect solution below:

```
<field name="category_ids" component="Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category" sortOrder="20" formElement="select">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <required>true</required>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
        </validation>
        <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
        <label translate="true">Categories</label>
        <dataScope>data.parent</dataScope>
        <componentType>field</componentType>
        <listens>
            <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
        </listens>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <select>
            <settings>
                <options class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options"/>
            </settings>
        </select>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Comment: Is this possible to get this tree structure in PHP ?

Comment: You should try using options class: Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options